# React Router flickering before rendering Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-redux, react-router

I'm currently developing an React App that runs as a Chrome Extension pop-up that uses redux, redux-persist (localForage) and react router. However, I'm experiencing flickering on the app. That is, when I click on the extension Icon to open the pop-up, it flickers white before rendering the desired Component.

I'm not sure as to why this is happening.

`Entrypoint (Popup.js)`

```
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    unsubscribe(); // make sure to only fire once
    render(
        <Provider store={storeWithMiddleware}>
            <PersistGate loading={<Loading />} persistor={persistor}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/main/modes"/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <ProtectedRoute path="/main" component={MainPage}/>
                </Router>
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
});
```

`ProtectedRouter`

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
  needsCheckLogin: needsCheckLogin,
  setNeedsCheckLogin: setNeedsCheckLogin,
  checkLogin: checkLogin,
  userKey: userKey,
  userUUID: userUUID,
  ...rest
}) => {
  // if (needsCheckLogin) {
  //   console.log("NEED LOGIN")
  //   console.log(userKey, userUUID)
  //   if (userKey && userUUID) {
  //     checkLogin(userKey, userUUID)
  //   }
  //   setNeedsCheckLogin(false);
  // }
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      // maybe props is in rest?
      render={props => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn,
    needsCheckLogin: state.auth.needsCheckLogin,
    userKey: state.settings.key,
        userUUID: state.settings.uuid,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setNeedsCheckLogin: value => dispatch(AuthAction.SetNeedsCheckedLogin(value)),
    checkLogin: (key, uuid) => dispatch(AuthAction.CheckLogin(key, uuid))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProtectedRoute);
```

The ProtectedRoute checks for user authentication when the app is first started, but the flickering doesn't disappear even when it's commented out.

GIFs of flicker:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKw0S.jpg

Comment: Looks like there is some "...loading..." text there briefly in the upper-right corner before the other UI loads, do you have anything that renders a "placeholder" text similar to that?

Comment: Yes, that's the Loading component for redux-persist. But I'm unsure of the blank loading before that text which happens on both GIFs - to answer your question, no I do not have anything

Comment: TBH I don't see a "flicker", but rather a blank area that is quickly rendered into, even after watching the gifs for a minute trying to understand the issue I don't see anything I'd call flickering. Are you saying there is some alternating back and forth between UI and blank space?

Comment: I'm not too sure. I was trying to mean the "blank space" when I say flickering, apologies. Initially I thought it was because of the Redirect from the default route but even if I removed that it still occurs.

Comment: This looks very much like normal behavior, IMO. Perhaps you can try hiding your UI entirely until your app state has been fully hydrated from storage to cut down any time spent displaying that "loading" placeholder. Just a guess there though.